# Program not printing anything ?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code in which I construct a 52 card pile, then deal the cards out to n number of players (it is possible for some players to have an extra card). The winner is the one with the Ace of Spades card.

```
public class CardGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 


    int numofPlayers = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    CardPile gameDeck = CardPile.makeFullDeck(); 
    CardPile [] players = new CardPile[numofPlayers];

    for (int i=0;i<numofPlayers;i++) {
      int numofnum = i%numofPlayers;
      players[i] = new CardPile();
    }

    for (int i=0;i<52;i++) {
      int numofnum =i%numofPlayers;
      CardPile curPlayer = players[i%numofPlayers];
      Card nextCard = gameDeck.get(i);
      players[numofnum].addToBottom(nextCard); 

    }
    for (int i=1;i<numofPlayers;i++) {
      if (players[i].find(Suit.SPADES, Value.ACE) != -1) {
        System.out.println("Player" + i + "has won!");
      }
    }

  }
}
```

When i try to run it with the command "java CardGame 5" the program runs but nothing is printed. Can anyone help ? Thanks !

Comment: Why would it print anything?

Comment: Maybe because no players has the ace of spades?

Comment: Shoudn't it print "player" + i +"has won" ?

Comment: There should always be a winner

Comment: I suspect your `CardPile:find` method is not working as expected...or possibly `get` or `addToBottom`...but you didn't include source for your `CardPile` class

Comment: And it should print something if there is, but it's not, so your assumption that there's always a winner seems wrong. Also, I note that you're not checking players[0], although if that was the only problem you'd sometimes get output.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`for (int i=1;i<numofPlayers;i++) {`

to:

```
for (int i=0;i<numofPlayers;i++) {
```

Since the index is zero based.